# ganache test returns characters instead of numbers

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, solidity-0.5.x, ganache-cli

```
 mapping(uint256 => uint256) public amount;

 function saveAmount(uint256 _id, uint256 _amount) public {
    amount[_id] = _amount;
 }
```

I have a function that saves amount in mapping. When I test this using ganache, I get a weird character values. 
For example,

`instance.saveAmount(1, 100000, {from: account[1]})`

then, to see the amount,

`instance.amount(1)` which yields

> BN: 186a0

Why is it not showing 100000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call is returning the hex value as a [big number](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html?highlight=isValidAddress#bn).

`0x186a0` in hex is `100000` in decimal.

It is a big number because it is easier to deal with ETH values in that format.

To get the number representation from the call, you should do the following:

```
var amount = instance.amount(1)
console.log(Number(amount))
```